# Using jquery plugin with vuejs, without webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I am having trouble figuring out how to use a jquery plugin within a vue component.  I am not using webkit, browserify, or ES2016.  Is there still a way for me to be able to use a plugin and target an element within the template tag? Google has yielded no results that were helpful.. the plugin in question is jquery.payment for stripe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin in the `ready` event of your component. In short it would look something like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ready: function() {
    jQuery('.find-thing').payment('formatCardNumber')
  }
})
```

Here's how I'd approach it if I had no other option. I did not test it but it should be relatively close:

```
<div id="app">
  <input class="payment-input" v-model="creditCardNumber">
  <div v-if="!creditCardNumberValid">BAD CC</div>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      creditCardNumber: '',
    },
    ready: function () {
      var paymentInput = this.$el.querySelector('.payment-input');
      jQuery(paymentInput).payment('formatCardNumber')
    },
    computed: {
      creditCardNumberValid: function () {
        return jQuery.payment.validateCardNumber(this.creditCardNumber)
      }
    }
  })
```